# OpenGL memory profiling with Linux and Intel HD

Tags: linux, opengl, memory, profiling

I have an OpenGL application that runs in Linux with an Intel GPU. I need to reduce the GPU memory consumption of my application. How can I profile effectively GPU memory?

I would like to be able to identify what parts are eating the most memory. For example, is it the textures or maybe the geometry? Is there any way I can query the memory that a texture or a buffer is consuming in OpenGL? Or are there any useful tools I can use for this?

Comment: I don't think you need any special profiler for that. Don't you know the sizes of all your textures and buffers already?

Comment: I'm not looking for a profiler, just some way to profile. There are things I don't know. For example, I have read that some GPUs don't really have RGB textures, that they are internally RGBA and the alpha channel is wasted. I'm not sure if this is true, so I would like to profile that.

Comment: It is true, and the GPU memory allocation for textures will further differ much more, as the image is chopped up into tiles of implementation-dependent size and stored in some non-linear memory layout. That's also the reason why a `N x 1` 2D texture will usually need much more memory than just a `N` wide 1D texture.